# MaltParser 1.5 PatternSyntaxException

Tags: java, nlp

I need to work with MaltParser 1.5 version for parsing russian sentences.
So, when I'm trying to type in cmd next command:

```
java -jar malt.jar
```

I'm getting next exception:

```
C:\malt1.5>java -jar malt.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at org.maltparser.MaltConsoleEngine.<init>(MaltConsoleEngine.java:29)
        at org.maltparser.Malt.main(Malt.java:17)
Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Unclosed character class near index 17
^.*malt[^\]*\.jar$
                 ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.clazz(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
        at org.maltparser.core.helper.SystemInfo.<init>(SystemInfo.java:28)
        at org.maltparser.core.helper.SystemInfo.<clinit>(SystemInfo.java:21)
        ... 2 more
```

I've tried to run this command whith JRE 1.5 and 1.8.45 - same result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be the `[^\]` part of the regex.  The `[` part starts a character class.  Ordinarily `]` ends a character class, but it's quoted with `\]` so you have written a character class that contains everything except the characters `]`, `*`, `.`, `j`, `a`, `r`, `$`, and is not terminated.

If the character class is supposed to contain everything except backslash, it should be `[^\\]` rather than `[^\]`.  To write the regex as a Java string, you will need an additional level of quoting:  `"[^\\\\]"`.  One level of quoting is for the regular expression and the other is for the string.

Comment: Thanks for reply. But I'm not strong in RegExps). Solution was to download 1.5.1 version of MaltParser (which was created to fix the issue, described by me above.) I just didn't have time to look through the version changes.